# Real analysis: Prove that a sequence in $(0,1)$ converging to $1$ has an increasing subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question is  "Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers, all of which lie in the open interval $(0, 1)$, and suppose $\lim a_n = 1.$ Prove that $\{a_n\}$ has an increasing subsequence".

I understand that for a sequence to be increasing its elements must be such that $ a_1 < a_2 < a_3 $ and so on, but how do I prove that using the fact that it is bounded and has a limit rather than with using the elements?

Thanks

Comment: The sequence $\langle 1, 1, 1,  \dotsc \rangle$ certainly converges to $1$, but has no increasing subsequence in your sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n_1=1$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1>a_{n_1}$, there is some $n_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_{n_2}>a_{n_1}$. And, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1>a_{n_2}$, there is some $n_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_{n_3}>a_{n_2}$. And so on…

Answer (score 0):

What about $b_1= a_1$ and

$$b_{n+1}=\inf \{a_k \mid a_k \gt \{b_1, \dots b_n,1-1/n\}\}$$